# Showing Wien's Displacement Law from Wien's Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermal-radiation

Does anyone know how I would show that $\lambda * T$ is constant, using only Wien's Law? That $\rho(\lambda,T) = 1/\lambda^5*f(\lambda T)$
I differentiated, but all I could get was $\lambda T = 5f(\lambda T)/f'(\lambda T)$, which I don't think means it's necessarily a constant.

Answer (score 5):

You are essentially there. Wien's law constricts the form of the blackbody spectrum to $$\rho(\lambda,T)=\frac{f(\lambda T)}{\lambda^5},$$ while Wien's displacement law talks about the *peak* of the spectrum at a given temperature. Thus you are correct that you need to set $\cfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial\lambda}=0$, and that this leads to the equation
$$5 f(\lambda T)=\lambda Tf'(\lambda T).\tag 1$$
This equation will look a lot more friendly if you introduce some more notation. If you set $\mu=\lambda T$, then you can reduce (1) to an equation that's exclusively in $\mu$:
$$5 f(\mu)= \mu f'(\mu).\tag 2$$
Depending on $f$, this may have one,  many, or no solutions, and each solution will mark a peak in the blackbody spectrum. Since Wien's law does not specify $f$, we can't tell yet, but we expect that there will be a unique solution $\mu_0$ to (2). This implies that the peak wavelength $\lambda_\text{peak}$ must obey
$$\lambda_\text{peak}=\frac{\mu_0}T.$$
Note that here $\mu_0$ is a (dimensionful) constant that is determined by the final form of $f$, but we know it can't depend on anything other than fundamental constants.

It's also important to note that this fact is part of a stronger result which is what Wien's law really embodies: a change in temperature can only make a scaling transformation on the corresponding blackbody spectrum. This is beautifully explored in [Using Wien's Law to show spectral distruibution function of one temperature represents all temperatures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76795/8563).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need more info, specifically the form of $f$:

$$ f = a e^{-b/(\lambda T)} $$

(Although not defined by Wien, this form of $f$ is now conventionally understood to be part of [Wien's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_approximation).)

---

Update:  With thanks to Emilio Pisanty and Pulsar, I see that a more general formulation is possible:   if $f$ is such that $\rho$ has a maximum at $\lambda_1$ at temperature $T_1$, the scaling argument [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76795/using-wiens-law-to-show-spectral-distruibution-function-of-one-temperature-repr) shows that the displacement law is valid.  The form I initially used, from Wien's approximation, is only a specific case.

Comment: I'm sorry, I downvoted without comment. The reason is that the form of $f$ is _not_ necessary to derive the result; see my answer.